# Download Files From a Website with java

Tags: java

I am very new to Java and I'm currently trying to create a Java application to download files from a website. To enter the website you need a password and username. I use `NativeSwing` to enter and get the path of the files, but I do not know how to download them.

```
public class Test {
public JFrame frame;
private static JWebBrowser browser;

private static JPanel configurationButtonPanel; 

public Test() {
    frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(createContent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(800, 800);
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public JComponent createContent() {

    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel configurationPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    configurationButtonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(
            FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
    JButton beginButton = new JButton("Download");
    beginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {



 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ArrayList<String> ligas = new ArrayList<String>();
            int a=0;
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(browser.getHTMLContent());
            Element ele = doc.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_PnlResultados");
            System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");

        try{
            Elements img_2 = ele.getElementsByClass("BtnDescarga");
            for (Element el : img_2) {



                for( Attribute attribute : el.attributes() )
                {

                    if( attribute.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("onclick") )
                    {

                       ligas.add("https://portalcfdi.facturaelectronica.sat.gob.mx/"+attribute.getValue().substring(19,535));

                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch(NullPointerException nulo){

        }


            for( int i = 0 ; i < ligas.size() ; i++ ){
                  System.out.println( ligas.get( i ) );

            }

        }

    });


    browser = new JWebBrowser();
    browser.navigate("https://portalcfdi.facturaelectronica.sat.gob.mx/");
    configurationButtonPanel.add(beginButton);
    configurationButtonPanel.setVisible(true);
    configurationPanel.add(configurationButtonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    contentPane.add(configurationPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    contentPane.add(browser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    return contentPane;
}
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NativeInterface.open();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            new Test();


        }
    });
    NativeInterface.runEventPump();

}

}
```

When it run this part:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < ligas.size() ; i++ ) {
    System.out.println( ligas.get( i ) );
}
```

I get the following URL:

```
https://portalcfdi.facturaelectronica.sat.gob.mx/RecuperaCfdi.aspx?Datos=huswUYX1eXMlGkDiItMUBgaWREHHqhXOWtYxqyUh0oUZnCKLYE/gx6ENJ+0TwW5auWw8d/AiCJyuFSDNVY+5l0vkiELroo/fEmF+x5w+DQDDTfMX9qIINS1NgP9C1bFhirjcVXpZI1ed4ycpLPczkYMEGEKvqWemni8LWcbqC0BuZskOJnCQCaWRh1Kt7AL5GdBVKqkm3T5mvzhtkmE5dn0vcWbCFFO3d3G8hu7rlcc0XM+7+6iR52SZYYaHa/TOhcl2DjuzztADpa9tPxZ9VO6EzMVkYKTfDOqHwZO8m2U9BZ7UhFjqsyoAwsQneqhIqGwN21yEpGEcptsTb9uZ1t0Fc/1Ggd6SuK9NeGdBpiawn6cv6QM1uc4QQHMNpAgG89Rq5tOd4YAoRQHBe/vO8ppq60JwvJgQ4BN76EtZF0UtEWK+k57P01vatuvTHIdMBncbXyU+TrtE5AlhdGKkY2a8HwSxHw3nfoQ+SLBrjyg=
```

Comment: Is it a requirement to display the downloaded HTML files?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to read images from url, i think you can use the same techniques here

```
 try{
        URL url = new URL("YOUR_URL_TO_READ");
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("YOUR_FILE_TO_SAVE");

        byte[] b = new byte[4096];
        int length;

        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();

        }catch(Exception exp){
            exp.printStackTrace(); 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer right now is the [Apache Http Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/). Java has `HttpURLConnection` built-in, but it is difficult to use, and has some other usage issues that can burn you (e.g. keep-alive and errors). If you absolutely cannot include a third party, use HttpURLConnection, otherwise go with the Apache Library.

There is a new Java standard Http library coming in JDK 9 [here](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/110), but that's not here yet.

Comment: do you have any example?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to try code on similar lines..it might work... Two issues maybe there...first is you need to find the proxy name and port set on your machine...if there is a proxy.. Next, possible the site needs authentication,so you would need to set the right username and password.

Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("Your Proxy", ProxyPort));

```
    String username = "YourUserName";
    String password = "Password";

    String userPassword = username + ":" + password;

     byte[] encodedAuthorization = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(userPassword.getBytes());    

     HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection)new URL("Your URL set here").openConnection(proxy);


     connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+ encodedAuthorization.toString());         

    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/zip");
    //connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

    InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("d:\\PathToFile" + "Chec.zip");
```